# Testing database

Tags: mysql, database

Hi I have created simple database containing several tables using MySQL.The types of the atributes are varchar, int, bigint, date, bite. Some tables have foreign keys to another tables.The cardinality is 1:1 or 1:M. I have task to test this database for educational purposes.But I have no idea for what database should be tested. Can you suggest what kind of tests should I perform and how. Also if some tool exists for such purposes will be nice. Thanks

Comment: For future reference SO questions asking for tool recommendations are often closed as Off Topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your brief is VERY broad, personally I'd design what tests you're going to do then OK them with your manager/mentor as you could well interpret this in a very different way to how it was intended.

I'm going to assume an online shopping system because it's easier to have an example.

Personally I'd test things like

- Can I create two Products (for the sake of argument) with the same name?
- Is it possible to create a Purchase (again I don't know your schema) for a product which doesn't exist?
- Is it possible to create a Purchase with a negative amount?

The key is you want to test scenarios which shouldn't be allowed. No one is given money for buying something, two products with the same name is confusing, you can't buy a nothing!

Also bear in mind that getting an error in much of these circumstances is actually the right result. If you try to create a purchase for a product which doesn't exist you expect the database to error when you try it.

Comment: Ok, this is an idea to test if there are errors on duplicate data, and if the retrieved data is the same as the one which is previously set.This way I can also test if my queries are correct. What about database "performance". I've heart this term but I am not sure if there is actually such think and how to be tested.

Comment: Database performance testing basically involves giving it a lot of data and a lot of work to do then measuring how long it takes. If you have the resources go for it!

Comment: can you suggest some automated tools which will do the job, and not to write whole program for measuring time, making queries etc.

Comment: I've not done a lot of automated DB testing I'm afraid.

Comment: I'd also add that performance testing is environment specific so is often harder to test with any real value (you have to replicate the  real system in terms of resource/workload). The sort of tests I recommended above can be done against any identical schema. If you're unsure what's required check back with the person who set the task.

Comment: Ok, the information you provided was very helpful. Thanks